# Licensing - Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, licensing

I know that the source code of linux kernel is licensed under GNU GPL V2.

Is there a way to view the change done to a module by a corporate company(say Cisco,Oracle)?
 Since the module must be disclosed once they change the code to fit their binary blob.

Comment: Why exactly are you asking? What you are afraid of? Publishing your source code when it is free software (GPL-ed) is common practice (see the *release early, release often* motto). What is your question (is it about modifying a GPL-ed source code, publishing or hiding it, or using it)?

Comment: Its just about the curiosity to know as what is happening? Just started to read about open source licensing. Your question is too intimidating for me since I have not touched a line of code in the kernel source.   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An individual or organization can put their code under any license they like, but unless it is GPLv2 or a compatible license it a) will not/cannot be included in the mainline kernel which can slow down adoption of the code, or b) cause legal issues for its users.

Comment: But the GPL mandates that any released modification must also be GPL. So there cannot be a separate corporate copyright. Isn't that right?

Comment: @tripleee: Copyright and license are two separate issues. Neither GPLv2 nor the Linux kernel dictate copyright.

Comment: Right. Just trying to use the terminology from the question. So what I suppose I meant is that a corporate fork cannot have a different license (or cannot be redistributed; I suppose it's okay to use a private fork internally).

Comment: You can't change the license of the overall product. You can have specific chunks of code under a different license though.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that unless you write kernel code from scratch  (for instance a self-contained kernel module), it's almost certain to be a derivative work of something that is GPL'd and therefore must also be.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux kernel is licensed under GNU GPL version 2. You can find the full text of the license [here](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html).

Comment: And there are some FAQ about it, e.g. http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html ; however, free software (notably big projects like the Linux kernel, or GCC, or Firefox) is also a social game with its rules and habits (and various communities).